# how open url with click on one div in Watin automation

Tags: watin

how open url with click on one div in Watin automation

i am going to url by this code

```
browser.GoTo(address);
browser.WaitForComplete();
```

and click on a div like this

```
var main_tab1 = browser.Div(Find.ByText("main_tab"));
main_tab1.click();
```

i want when browser going to url the div be cliked

and no need to click ... and the automation will be faster

Comment: the main_tab1 div have onclick parameter that equal to : onclick="__doPostBack('HstUnitExchangeLetterSendEdit$tabControl1','1')"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your question right. You are asking whether you need to navigate to page on click on Div using browser.Goto(address)? If so, try to navigate directly to the address. Capture the URL when u click on the div and send it to GOTO method.

Comment: thanks for your answer but the url before and after i click on div is one thing and no change . and i can only capture url before click div.

Comment: It seems I have not got your question well. Can you please try to post the complete code and what each lines does as comment.

Answer (score 0):

i click on a button

```
var repbtn = browser.Button(Find.ById("btnReply"));
repbtn.Click();
```

and goto a page after click on btnReply

and in this page i have 4 tabs that i must click on one of theme

in this page i capture url with this code

```
string rep_url=browser.Url;
browser.Goto(rep_url);
```

and when i click on one of 4 tabs the url not changed that i captured its url

```
var main_tab = browser3.Div(Find.ByText("main"));
main_tab.Click();
```

the main_tab Div have onclick method , do i run this method even url loading .